# Meaning of terms identical, equal, equivalent in the Standard

Tags: c++, std

There are at least three terms with similar meaning in the Standard: *identical*, *equal* and *equivalent*. All these used when algorithms described. Say, `std::adjacent_find`:

> Searches the range `[first, last)` for two consecutive identical elements.

But description of the comparator says:

> binary predicate which returns ​true if the elements should be treated as equal

When it comes to associative containers, the word *equivalent* is used. For two elements `a` and `b` it means (roughly) `!(a < b) && !(b < a)`. While *equal* means `a == b`.

What does the term *identical* mean? Is it defined in the Standard?

Comment: Where did the first quote come from?

Comment: @StoryTeller Really not from the standard, but from cppreference. Sorry.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no definition of "identical" that I could find in the relevant sections of the standard. Looks like a colloquial use of the word. Which is further supported by the fact your quote is from cppreference. The normative definition of `adjacent_find` in the standard is [specified in terms of `==` 
 (or a predicate) directly](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/alg.adjacent.find#lib:adjacent_find):

> *Returns*: The first iterator `i` such that both `i` and `i + 1` are in the range [first, last) for which the following corresponding conditions
>   hold: `*i == *(i + 1)`, `pred(*i, *(i + 1)) != false`. Returns last if no
>   such iterator is found.

While cppreference is an invaluable resource, its goal is to digest the standard text into easily accessible and understandable materiel. Sometimes, it will make colloquial use of words for an intuitive explanation. This is one such case.

Comment: As I know in `std::adjacent_find` it is legal to use, say `std::greater_equal` (or negation of `std::less`) as comparator to check a range, that it `std::is_sorted` and (imaginary) `std::is_unique` at once. `Specified in terms of == directly` refers to form without `comp` comparator.

Comment: @Orient - You may indeed. The quote supports it. I too made an error in phrasing by focusing on `==` alone :) I'm a mere mortal